# How to call javascript function from html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have following code:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'order_id'">
        {{ x.order_id + ', ' + x.table_id+', '+x.name+', '+x.phone+', '+x.address+', '+x.remark+', '+myFunction(x.ctime)}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

I want to call myFunction and get the returned value, but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(ctime) {
    alert("Hello World!");

    // create a new javascript Date object based on the timestamp
    // multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds
    var date = new Date(ctime*1000);
    // hours part from the timestamp
    var hours = date.getHours();
    // minutes part from the timestamp
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    // seconds part from the timestamp
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    // will display time in 10:30:23 format
    var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    console.log("debug",formattedTime);
    return formattedTime;
}

</script>
```

I wonder to know where the problem is. thanks.

Comment: Try +<script>myFunction(x.ctime)</script>

Comment: @sajanyamaha, thanks. but it didn't work...

Comment: Try `<ion-item ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'order_id'" ng-init="myFunction(x.ctime)"`>

Comment: do you use angular? how _it doesn't work._? do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: why you add code lines after `return` statement? this code never execute

Comment: @evc, thanks,  unfortunately it still didn't work...

Comment: @Grundy, thanks for concerns. yes, I use angular. I didn't see any errors in  browser console. the code lines after return statement is mistype(for testing), forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of your `script` being attached in your page and your `expression` being evaluated might be the problem.

Anyways, making a global `JavaScript` function directly in the html file is not really recommended. You are using `AngularJS`, you can make the function available in the relevant `scope`, which will automatically handle this for you.

---

You must be having some `controller` where you declared your object array `names`, which must be looking something like:

```
myApp.controller('NamesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{order_id: 1, table_id: 4, name: "Someone"}];
}]);
```

Just add your `myFunction` to the scope of the controller like:

```
myApp.controller('NamesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{order_id: 1, table_id: 4, name: "Someone"}];

  $scope.myFunction = function myFunction(ctime) {
    alert("Hello World!");

    // create a new javascript Date object based on the timestamp
    // multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds
    var date = new Date(ctime*1000);
    // hours part from the timestamp
    var hours = date.getHours();
    // minutes part from the timestamp
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    // seconds part from the timestamp
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    // will display time in 10:30:23 format
    var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    console.log("debug",formattedTime);
    return formattedTime;
  };
}]);
```

The expression through which you are calling the function needs no change.

If you want more details about this concept you may have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#adding-behavior-to-a-scope-object).

---

If you still choose to keep your `script` in the html page, you may try to include that script before the expression and check if it solves the issue.

If you still have any issues, feel free to comment.

Comment: thanks @Kamran Ahmed, I defined myFunction before I call it, I think the sequence is fine.

Comment: Why not in the scope of that object? Try doing that, it should surely fix it.

Comment: I'm new to angular and javascript, I don't know how to do in the scope of that object. Could you help to show me? thanks.